# Getting an error setting up phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to set up phpmyadmin. But when i enter "http://'localhost'/~username/", it gives the following error:

> Not Found - The requested URL /~username/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Remove the quotes in `http://'localhost'/~username/` try `http://localhost/~username/` if that's what you're actually typing in.

Comment: In which directory did you install phpmyadmin?

Comment: Did you try http://localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: *"Ladies & Gentlemen* **:::[ELVIS](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3105881/user3105881):::** *has left the building."*